# Firebase database offline cache not working between launches

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to use Firebase for a partially offline app, it seems to have all the offline capabilities I need but I'm having issues with fetching data while offline. The JSON structure I want to store is a single reference to a user profile:

```
{
  "Profiles" : {
     "pOnv3q1PxqPyqKH0uqtDYaXqvqF2" : {
      "firstName" : "John",
      "lastName" : "Doe"
    }
  }
}
```

I've set `Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true` and `keepSynced(true)` set for the reference I want to keep cached offline. I set `keepSynced(true)` both when I create the reference the first time and when I load it on subsequent launches.

## Scenario 1 - Works

If I launch the app online, the reference is created and saved to the online database. If I close the app with it still online and fully kill it, then relaunch, the reference is found as you'd expect.

## Scenario 2 - Works

I launch the app offline, create the reference offline and save it to the cache. I fully kill the app and relaunch it and then reconnect, the reference is pushed to the online database from the cache as you'd expect.

## Scenario 3 - Does not work

I launch the app online, create the reference and exit while still online. I kill the app and then relaunch it offline, only to find that the reference had not been stored in the cache and isn't being loaded.

These scenarios seem to me like the requests to the online database are being successfully cached, but the database itself is not.

Am I misunderstanding the Firebase offline functionality or should this be working? It's worth noting that this is in **Xcode9, iOS11 and Swift 4** so there may be compatibility issues.

The code I'm using to fetch this reference is:

```
Database.database().child("Profiles").child(userId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
    print(snapshot)
}
```

On failed fetches this is returning an empty snapshot. I was under the impression that if the local cache had no idea of the presence of a key then the completion handler wouldn't be called, however it is being called leading me to think that the key exists but the data isn't being fetched properly.

Ideally the user would be able to sign up offline and have basic functionality, then push the data when a connection is established, but currently the profile can only be loaded with a connection available.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Firebase is really designed to be an online database, with persistence to handle situations where an app is temporarily offline. I don't think your question can be answered without a lot more code and troubleshooting. Perhaps it would be better to utilize another database (Realm? MySQL?) locally for offline and leverage Firebase for synchronization and sharing of data. Just a thought...

Comment: Was this ever resolved? Did you end up using another service for local data storage?